# Android ListView item blinks on selection

Tags: android, android-listview

I am creating a custom ListView as below

Main Layout

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center">

    <ListView android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="3dip"  
    android:fadingEdge="none"
    android:soundEffectsEnabled="true"       
    android:clickable="true"                
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:divider="#ffcccccc"
    android:dividerHeight="1dip"                
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Custom ListView

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:background="@drawable/sellistitem">  
  <TextView
   android:id="@+id/ListItem"       
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="30dip"
   android:layout_margin="1dip"             
   android:textColor="@color/BLACK"
   android:gravity="center_vertical"
   android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
   android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
   android:padding="5dip"/>           
</RelativeLayout>
```

and Selector as below

```
<selector 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/BLUE" /> 
<item android:drawable="@drawable/WHITE" /> 
</selector>
```

The Drawable

```
 <resources>
    <drawable name="WHITE">#ffffff</drawable>
    <drawable name="BLUE">#ff0033cc</drawable>
 </resources>
```

Having done this the selection part works fine. However when I click on any item ,the selected item blinks twice before actually changing to blue. It doesn't change to blue directly as it should. How can I remove this blinking effect?

Regards,

Comment: **When** does it blink twice? Can you explain that better?

Comment: @dmon Sorry its when any list item is clicked to select.

Comment: What are @drawable/WHITE and @drawable/BLUE?

Comment: I have also added the code for the 2 drawables also. Please have a look above.

Answer (score 0):

try this `android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"` to `listview`

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't solve the problem. Thanks Anyways.

Comment: why not use android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent" instead?

Answer (score 0):

Selectors are tricky, in general. Try this for your selector instead:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_pressed="true" 
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/selected_background" />
  <item android:state_focused="false" 
        android:state_pressed="false" 
        android:state_selected="false"
        android:state_checked="false" 
        android:state_enabled="true" 
        android:state_checkable="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/normal_background"/>
</selector>
```

Note that the `android:drawable attribute` *does not* have to be a drawable. If it's a simple color you can reference it with the `@color/background_color` format.

EDIT:

Ok, those white and blue "drawables" aren't drawables, they're just colors, you're better off defining them in the `colors.xml`. It could be that that is actually the reason for the flickering.

```
<resources>
    <color name="blue">#ff0033cc</color>
    <color name="white">#ffffff</color>
</resources>
```